# Save data from a textbox to a specific line in an existing text file

Tags: c#, textbox, save

I have a text file with these inside,

> Apple 5[KG]
>   Orange 7[KG]
>   Water 10[L]

I have written this, to get a specific location from the text file

```
//a function to get a value between two different strings
public static string getBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
{
    int Start, End;
    if (strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
    {
        Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 0) + strStart.Length;
        End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
        return strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start);
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

And I'm using this to display the value in the textBox, (After the selecting the file and loading and stuff)

```
textBox1.Text = getBetween(filetext, "Apple ", "[");
//filetext is a string that contains the selected file's name
```

If I were to use similar method (or a better method) to replace the value of apple's weight by editing the value from the same textbox, what are the changes I need to make or what is the code segment for a "putBetween" function or something?

Comment: Must it be a text file?  Something like an xml file would be easier to edit.

Comment: You could read the text file into a variable, split it, then concat the text with your insertion, and write the changed text back to the text file.

Comment: Yes it must be a text file, is there any alternative method to this?

Comment: There are different ways of replacing the string. When it comes to the file however, you will probably have to write the whole thing back to disk.

Comment: You will have to write it back because the new line may be larger or smaller than the existing line so, even if you could locate it in the file by memory mapping it you wouldn't be able to store the text.

Comment: [Memory mapped files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files) are a possibility, but they are horribly inefficient in .NET because you have to cross over into unmanaged. You would be better off to read everything in, modify it and write everything out.